# r package development: When to use ::

Tags: r, dependencies

a question on coding conventiosn: I am working on an r package and I want to submit it to cran. All external functions are correctly imported in the NAMESPACE file. Do I have to use :: to specify the package in my source code or is everything fine by providing the imports in the namespace? Example
In the NAMESPACE, there is something like

```
importFrom(stats, formula, ave, aggregate, median, sd, qnorm, rnorm, runif)
```

Do I have to explicetly call stats when using e.g.g rnorm

```
random <- stats::rnorm(100, m = 0, sd = 1)
```

or can I leave out 'stats::' with respect to cran policies?

Comment: It's definitely better if you use `stats::` in your code.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `importFrom` it's not *necessary*; from Hadley Wickham's [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html):

> If you are using just a few functions from another package, my
>   recommendation is to note the package name in the Imports: field of
>   the DESCRIPTION file and call the function(s) explicitly using ::,
>   e.g., pkg::fun(). Operators can also be imported in a similar manner,
>   e.g., @importFrom magrittr %>%.
>
> If you are using functions repeatedly, you can avoid :: by importing
>   the function with @importFrom pkg fun. This also has a small
>   performance benefit, because :: adds approximately 5 µs to function
>   evaluation time.

However, many see it as good practice to use `::` in terms of making your code explicit and readable; if anyone looks at your source code, they know precisely where the functions you're calling come from.

Comment: Many thanks (to all) for the very quick answers. So the call is more or less a performance issue for repeated calling, e. g. in iterative functions, I guess, and if this is not a problem, :: should be added for readability, right?
What about calls to function from my own package? Should there :: be added or generally not?

Comment: @user1227776 That's right. I almost always use `::` for the readability issue, but for repeated calling you could gain performance. Each use of `::` only adds about 5 microseconds, so it's up to you and highly context dependent on whether it's a sufficient performance boost to hamper readability.

Comment: @user1227776 I just noticed the last sentence in your comment there. You do not need `::` for functions from your own package.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the `::` in your code.  Importing those items makes them available locally.

As Nicola said, there are arguments why you could use `::`.  It makes it clear where the function came from.  However, if you do use `::`, there is no point in importing the function:  the `rnorm` object imported into your namespace would be ignored.

For myself, I would import rather than use the `::`.  A call to an imported function has less overhead than a call to `::` to resolve a call into an external package.